# Json, javascript and treeview

Tags: javascript, json, treeview

I have a data in json include some folder structure like that:
[Here the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPxkG.png)

please don't see some div tags and scripts.

I want to make a directory tree with this datas. I coded something but not excatly works.

here my javascript codes

```
<script>

    function printChildren(mainFolder){
        var mainTag = document.createElement("ul");
        
           
            mainFolder.children.forEach(element => {
                
                
                subTag = document.createElement("li");
                
                if(element.hasOwnProperty("children")){
                    mainTag.className = "mainFolder"
                    var spanElement = document.createElement('span');
                    
                    spanElement.innerHTML = element.data;
                    
                    subTag.append(spanElement);
                    mainTag.append(subTag)
                    printChildren(element);
                }
                else {
                    subTag.innerHTML = element.data;
                    
                }
                
                
                
                
               
                
            });
            document.getElementById("rootFolder").appendChild(mainTag);
            
            
            

        
    }
    var data = document.getElementById("data");
    dataJson = JSON.parse(data.innerHTML);
    
    (printChildren(dataJson));

</script>
```

Here the result of the codes:

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPkg9.png)

rootFolder is ul tag. Just ul tag.

[Here the datas](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/pDDZj6RpCz/) that I used in javascript codes

Thank you so much.

Comment: please share the fetch data URL or text data. It's for testing

Comment: @MingqiZhao I edited the post. I added the datas to last words.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Recurisve Function effectively.
So we can input the data by depth and sorted by depth decendently.
And merge the elements.

```js
function printChildren(mainFolder) {
  const mainEle = document.createElement("ul");
  const ans = {};

  const childRecurisve = (ele, depth) => {
    if (ele && ele.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
      ele.children.forEach(chld => childRecurisve(chld, depth + 1));
      if (!(depth in ans)) {
        ans[depth] = []
      }
      ans[depth].push(ele.data);
    }
  }

  childRecurisve(mainFolder, 0);

  let result = []
  Object.keys(ans).reverse().map(item => result = [...result, ...ans[item]])


  result.map(item => {
    const subEle = document.createElement("li");
    const spanEle = document.createElement('span');
    spanEle.innerHTML = item
    subEle.append(spanEle)
    mainEle.append(subEle)
  });
  document.getElementById("rootFolder").appendChild(mainEle)
}
var data = document.getElementById("data");
dataJson = JSON.parse(data.innerHTML);

(printChildren(dataJson));
```

```html
<div id="rootFolder"></div>
<div id='data' style='display: none;'>
  {"data":"upload","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload"},"children":[{"data":"Dataset1","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1"},"children":[{"data":"At","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/At"},"children":[{"data":"test","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/At\/test"},"children":["BfMeamV6v68.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4.jpg"]},{"data":"train","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/At\/train"},"children":["G1T9diHtrHU.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78.jpg","ads.jpg","ads2.jpg","ads3.jpg","ads4.jpg","ads5.jpg","ads6.jpg","ads7.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM.jpg","oMctjevEhs8.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s.jpg"]},{"data":"validation","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/At\/validation"},"children":["b0t7x2lUTPQ.jpg"]}]},{"data":"Ceylan","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Ceylan"},"children":[{"data":"test","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Ceylan\/test"},"children":["BfMeamV6v68.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_rot_left10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_rot_right10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68rot_right-10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_rot_left10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_rot_right10.jpg","rot_-10BfMeamV6v68.jpg","rot_10BfMeamV6v68.jpg"]},{"data":"train","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Ceylan\/train"},"children":["G1T9diHtrHU.jpg","G1T9diHtrHU_rot_left10.jpg","G1T9diHtrHU_rot_right10.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY_rot_left10.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY_rot_right10.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4_rot_left10.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4_rot_right10.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78_rot_left10.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78_rot_right10.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM_rot_left10.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM_rot_right10.jpg","oMctjevEhs8.jpg","oMctjevEhs8_rot_left10.jpg","oMctjevEhs8_rot_right10.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s_rot_left10.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s_rot_right10.jpg"]},{"data":"validation","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Ceylan\/validation"},"children":["b0t7x2lUTPQ.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_rot_left10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_rot_right10.jpg"]}]},{"data":"E\u015fek","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/E\u015fek"},"children":[{"data":"test","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/E\u015fek\/test"},"children":["BfMeamV6v68.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4.jpg"]},{"data":"train","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/E\u015fek\/train"},"children":["G1T9diHtrHU.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM.jpg","oMctjevEhs8.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s.jpg"]},{"data":"validation","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/E\u015fek\/validation"},"children":["b0t7x2lUTPQ.jpg"]}]},{"data":"Geyik","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Geyik"},"children":[{"data":"test","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Geyik\/test"},"children":["BfMeamV6v68.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4.jpg"]},{"data":"train","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Geyik\/train"},"children":["G1T9diHtrHU.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM.jpg","oMctjevEhs8.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s.jpg"]},{"data":"validation","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Geyik\/validation"},"children":["b0t7x2lUTPQ.jpg"]}]},{"data":"Karga","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Karga"},"children":[{"data":"test","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Karga\/test"},"children":["BfMeamV6v68.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_rot_left10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_rot_left_10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_rot_right10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_rot_right_10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_sized_down0.2.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_sized_down_0.2.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_sized_down_0.8.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_sized_down_1.2.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_sized_up1.2.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_sized_up_1.2.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_translated_bottom_10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_translated_bottom_right_10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_translated_left_10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_translated_left_up10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_translated_right_10.jpg","BfMeamV6v68_translated_up_10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_rot_left10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_rot_left_10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_rot_right10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_rot_right_10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_sized_down0.2.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_sized_down_0.2.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_sized_down_0.8.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_sized_down_1.2.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_sized_up1.2.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_sized_up_1.2.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_translated_bottom_10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_translated_bottom_right_10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_translated_left_10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_translated_left_up10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_translated_right_10.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4_translated_up_10.jpg"]},{"data":"train","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Karga\/train"},"children":["G1T9diHtrHU.jpg","G1T9diHtrHU_rot_left_10.jpg","G1T9diHtrHU_rot_right_10.jpg","G1T9diHtrHU_sized_down_0.8.jpg","G1T9diHtrHU_sized_down_1.2.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY_rot_left_10.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY_rot_right_10.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY_sized_down_0.8.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY_sized_down_1.2.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4_rot_left_10.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4_rot_right_10.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4_sized_down_0.8.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4_sized_down_1.2.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78_rot_left_10.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78_rot_right_10.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78_sized_down_0.8.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78_sized_down_1.2.jpg","denem1.jpg","denem2.jpg","denem3.jpg","denem4.jpg","denem5.jpg","denem6.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM_rot_left_10.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM_rot_right_10.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM_sized_down_0.8.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM_sized_down_1.2.jpg","oMctjevEhs8.jpg","oMctjevEhs8_rot_left_10.jpg","oMctjevEhs8_rot_right_10.jpg","oMctjevEhs8_sized_down_0.8.jpg","oMctjevEhs8_sized_down_1.2.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s_rot_left_10.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s_rot_right_10.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s_sized_down_0.8.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s_sized_down_1.2.jpg"]},{"data":"validation","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Karga\/validation"},"children":["b0t7x2lUTPQ.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_rot_left10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_rot_left_10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_rot_right10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_rot_right_10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_sized_down0.2.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_sized_down_0.2.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_sized_down_0.8.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_sized_down_1.2.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_sized_up1.2.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_sized_up_1.2.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_translated_bottom_10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_translated_bottom_right_10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_translated_left_10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_translated_left_up10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_translated_right_10.jpg","b0t7x2lUTPQ_translated_up_10.jpg"]}]},{"data":"Kaz","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Kaz"},"children":[{"data":"test","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Kaz\/test"},"children":["BfMeamV6v68.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4.jpg"]},{"data":"train","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Kaz\/train"},"children":["G1T9diHtrHU.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM.jpg","oMctjevEhs8.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s.jpg"]},{"data":"validation","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Kaz\/validation"},"children":["b0t7x2lUTPQ.jpg"]}]},{"data":"Tav\u015fan","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Tav\u015fan"},"children":[{"data":"test","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Tav\u015fan\/test"},"children":["BfMeamV6v68.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4.jpg"]},{"data":"train","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Tav\u015fan\/train"},"children":["G1T9diHtrHU.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM.jpg","oMctjevEhs8.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s.jpg"]},{"data":"validation","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/Tav\u015fan\/validation"},"children":["b0t7x2lUTPQ.jpg"]}]},{"data":"\u00d6rdek","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/\u00d6rdek"},"children":[{"data":"test","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/\u00d6rdek\/test"},"children":["BfMeamV6v68.jpg","YqLhPqscbz4.jpg"]},{"data":"train","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/\u00d6rdek\/train"},"children":["G1T9diHtrHU.jpg","HjxY9EE9eVY.jpg","VZ6I1h9M2F4.jpg","W6NkVXrzH78.jpg","fTarkVHhmDM.jpg","oMctjevEhs8.jpg","vfeBNdpkQ-s.jpg"]},{"data":"validation","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset1\/\u00d6rdek\/validation"},"children":["b0t7x2lUTPQ.jpg"]}]}]},{"data":"Dataset2","attr":{"rel":"folder"},"metadata":{"id":"upload\/Dataset2"},"children":[]}]}

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I tried your solution but not what I want. In your solution and my, result is same but I want to treeview, not like that. I reviewed your solution, we should create a hierarchical structure. Dataset1 should include Eşek, Geyitk, Karga... And they should include train, validation and test. But in this structure, all of them is in same array.